# ChangeLog (_cl) table implementation for indexing in Magento2

Tags: magento2, indexing, indexer

Is there a changelog table implementation for indexing in Magento2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When index mode is `update by schedule` then change log table  will create for that index.it contains version_id and entity_id.

These records will inserted by mysql triggers.

For more information look at `Magento/framework/mview`